# where should I use return statement

Tags: python, return

My code is working properly but it is not verified as True or False.
My question was, 
"Write a function replace(s, old, new) that replaces all occurrences of old with new in a string s"

I tried return instead of print but then the result comes "None"

```py
def replace(s, old, new):
    ss = s.split(old)
    js = new.join(ss)
    print(js)

replace("Mississippi", "i", "I") == "MIssIssIppI"


expected result would be True or False.
```

Comment: remove print and wrtie return js

Comment: I did that but then the output becomes None.

Comment: it is working fine for me

Comment: @AsifIqbal Show your attempt because what you describe won't happen with the code you have. Also show how you're printing what `replace` returns, as you aren't printing the return here.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me Actually I did not print the replace function when i used return. @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0):

`return` gives the result back, but you have to assign it to a variable to use it (or use the whole function call directly). So if you change `print(js)` to `return js` and do `print(replace("Mississippi", "i", "I"))`, you should get `MIssIssIppI`

If instead you do

```
output = replace("Mississippi", "i", "I")
if output ==  "MIssIssIppI":
   print('True')
else:
   print('False')

#OR

print(output == 'MIssIssIppI') #simpler way
```

you will get your desired results.

`return` allows you to assign the result of the function as a variable and do with it as you like.

`replace("Mississippi", "i", "I")` does not print anything (if you change your print statement to a return statement), but it returns its result, but you are not doing anything with it.

Comment: Thank you for the replay but then the result is "MIssIssIppI" and "False". I need a single answer true or False only.

Comment: @AsifIqbal Your code doesn't do anything useful right now. It's just splits a string then rejoins it. Note how you never use `new`. The question you asked has been answered. You'll need to work on making the function operate properly now, which is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the return and print function to me. I understood the my mistake. @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `print()` with it, like this:

```
def replace(s, old, new):
    ss = s.split(old)
    js = new.join(ss)
    return js
```

Then you can just print the result of the comparison with:

```
print(replace("Mississippi", "i", "I") == "MIssIssIppI")
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
def replace(s, old, new):
    ss = s.split(old)
    js = new.join(ss)
    return js

print(replace("Mississippi", "i", "I") == "MIssIssIppI")
```

This works just fine for me, after adding return statement to function and print while calling the comparison.